# Finding the particular solution of a system of differential equation (first order)

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

From:
$$x' -\begin{bmatrix} -7&9 \\ -6&8 \end{bmatrix}x = \begin{bmatrix} 4e^t \\ 3e^t\end{bmatrix} $$

i know that the solution x from this non-homogenous equation consists of a homogenous part and a particular solution:
$$x = x_H + x_P$$

So i found the eigenvalues and vectors:
$$\lambda_1 = 2, vector= \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix} $$
$$\lambda_2 = 1, vector= \begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $$

hence the homogenous solution is:
$$x_H = Ae^{2t}\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}+Be^{-t}\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \end{bmatrix} $$

Now for $x_P$ i have almost no idea i think.... It's like
$$x_P' - \begin{bmatrix} -7&9 \\ -6&8 \end{bmatrix}x_P = \begin{bmatrix} 4e^t \\ 3e^t\end{bmatrix}  $$

Where $x_p = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha \\ \beta \end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix} \gamma \\ \delta \end{bmatrix} $

Answer (score 0):

Well, when RHS has inhomogeneity of form $v e^{\alpha t}$ ($v \in \mathbb{R}^n$) and $\alpha$ is not a root of characteristic equation, you may search particular solution in the same form $\hat{v} e^{\alpha t}$. And it will work:

$$ \alpha \hat{v} e^{\alpha t} = (A \hat{v}) e^{\alpha t} + v e^{\alpha t}$$
$$ (\alpha E - A) \hat{v} = v, \; \det{(\alpha E - A)} \neq 0 $$
$$ \hat{v} = (\alpha E - A)^{-1} v $$

Also, the second eigenvalue is $-1$, not $1$.